# Select in select relation order in CakePHP 3

Tags: php, cakephp

I have problem with order in cakephp paginate.

My code view like this:

```
 $list = $this->paginate(
            $this->Akwaria->find()
                ->select(['countDrugs'=>"(SELECT COUNT(`ad`.`id`) FROM `akwaria_drugs` `ad` WHERE `ad`.`id_akwaria` = Akwaria.id)"])
                ->select($this->Akwaria)
                ->where($where),['limit'=>'30','order'=>['id'=>'desc']]
        );
```

and in ctp files I have line like this:

```
<th><?= $this->Paginator->sort('countDrugs', "Podanych Leków") ?></th>
```

My problem is that it needs to be able to sort the column to the column "countDrugs" But this is not the standard way of working, and in the documentation I can find the instructions as if such a relationship to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> By default sorting can be done on any non-virtual column a table has.
>   This is sometimes undesirable as it allows users to sort on un-indexed
>   columns that can be expensive to order by. You can set the whitelist
>   of fields that can be sorted using the **sortWhitelist** option. This
>   option is required when you want to sort on any associated data, or
>   computed fields that may be part of your pagination query:

[Control which Fields Used for Ordering](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/pagination.html#control-which-fields-used-for-ordering)

In your case use like this

```
$this->paginate = [
    'sortWhitelist' => [
        'countDrugs',
    ],
];
```

Its tested and working well